# Loading content around TextBoxes in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm trying to create a form in ASP.NET but I'd like to know if I can dynamically add HTML content around a TextBox.

Here is the code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MPpacientes.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CuestionarioGeneral.aspx.cs" Inherits="CuestionarioGeneral" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="navbar" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="headertitle" Runat="Server">
Cuestionario General
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="contentbox" Runat="Server">
<legend>Lorem ipsum dolor sia met etcetcetc</legend>
<%-- question1 --%>
<asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text="1"></asp:Label>
<div class="input-control text" data-role="input-control">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <button class="btn-clear" tabindex="-1"></button>
</div>
<%-- question2 --%>
<asp:Label ID="lbl2" runat="server" Text="2"></asp:Label>
<div class="input-control text" data-role="input-control">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <button class="btn-clear" tabindex="-1"></button>
</div>
<%-- question3 --%>
   <%-- etc --%>
```

As you can see in the code, the content of the < div > and the < button > tags don't change at all in each question, so I wanna know if there's some way to load them from a script so that when the page loads they wrap around each TextBox automatically.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the reasoning for this? It would be more accessible if you keep the HTML separate and not append it on the fly using JavaScript.

Comment: i dont understand your question. can you please tell me any example here?

Comment: The thing is that the form I'm making has several other pages with many questions in each one. So if I have to change the button or the div tag it's gonna take quite a long time.

Comment: I like using JsRender for that sort of thing. It stores html and you can pass in variables which are rendered by the javascript.

Comment: http://dotnet--solutions.blogspot.in/2012/12/create-dynamic-textbox-and-dropdownlist.html

Comment: JsRender is KINDA what I want but I as far as I know I can't create ASP Content using Javascript. But anyways, I'll try it tomorrow and see if it works. I'm open to more suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did the total question for each page different or the same?
if different, you can try to use `asp:Repeater` for that. You can dynamically change the question, and keep the button and div static for every question.

for example :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptQuestion" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptQuestion_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblQuestion"></asp:Label>
        <div class="input-control text" data-role="input-control">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAnswer" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button CssClass="btn-clear" TabIndex="-1" ID="btnClear" runat="server"></button>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Edit :**

to edit the Label text, you can first add all your question to `List<String>` then Bind it to the repeater, here's the example :

on PageLoad :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<String> listQuestion = new List<String>();

        foreach(string question in ...)
        {
            listQuestion.Add(question);
        }

        rptQuestion.DataSource = listQuestion;
        rptQuestion.DataBind();
    }
```

then on the ItemDataBound event :

```
protected void rptQuestion_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                String question = (String)e.Item.DataItem;
                Label lblQuestion = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblQuestion");
                lblQuestion.Text = question;
            }
        }
```

you don't need to change the ID for the Label and TextBox, because it will always be different for each item in the repeater

Comment: Exactly. Each page has a different amount of different questions. Now, how exactly can I change the Label ID, Label Text and TextBox ID for each question with this? I've seen some examples but they're not well explained. Sorry to bother, but I'm still learning asp.net.

Comment: edited the answer with more explanation on how to use the Repeater

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to add a question, you can a `<asp:label />` tag, or even a Html `label` tag and make it `runat="server"`.
And then you can add the text to the label dynamically in the code behind